# js style properties returns blank of the style css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use the div's css properties for my js conditional statement.

I have this code of css :

```
div.desc{
   position:relative;
   top:0px;
   left:0px;
}
```

now, I want to use it in my js so I try to alert the top.

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('desc')[0].style.top)
```

but I got the blank return.

Does my code done wrong? or it is possible that I can get the css property of the div class desc using js?

Comment: if can please post your html code part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jquery.

```
alert($('.desc').eq(0).css('top'));
```

Comment: That will give you a list of them. The OP wants the first one.

Comment: That is ok. Just as an aside does the `css` function return the CSS style from the CSS file or the computed style?

Comment: You can check out the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/). It functions like the getComputedStyle() method in standards-based browsers.

Comment: I thought you might know off the top of your head. But according to the text book (that unfortunately was at the bottom of the pile of books on my desk!) it does the calculation. The devil is in the detail.

Answer (score 0):

Does the first item that has the class `desc` have the style top set? If not it is inherited or inferred.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it like this

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('desc')[0];
var comp = el.currentStyle || getComputedStyle(el, null);
alert( comp.top );
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/42Uw8/)

​